# Microsoft Graph - Invalid filter clause

Tags: javascript, node.js, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am trying to filter by `conversationId` to get messages and replies for mail, but I am getting an error each time:

> ```
> Unexpected error value: 
> {
>   statusCode: 400, 
>   code: "BadRequest",
>   message: "Invalid filter clause"
> ```

Example code:

```
let response = 
  await client.api(`/me/messages?$filter=conversationId eq '${conversationId}'`)
  .get();
```

The request path outputs like this:

```
/me/messages?$filter=conversationId eq 'AAQkADJkZTNiN2ZlLTg2M2QtNGZjMC1hNDUxLTdlNjgzZDVjZDljMAAQAKVNpsZfVhlEtPFltSQuNJ8='
```

When trying the exact same path in [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) there is no issue at all.

Has it something to do with the spaces? Should I add `%20`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by using this instead from the [documentation](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/blob/dev/docs/QueryParameters.md):

```
.filter(`conversationId eq '${id}'`)
```